# Bizarre Environment-dependent Bad Request 400 error

Tags: gunicorn, uwsgi, flask-restful

I'm writing a program to convert a repository into a Docker with an API based on some specification files. When I run the app on my Macbook's base environment, the computer-generated API works perfectly with both gunicorn and uwsgi. However, within the `miniconda`-based docker container, it failed with `Bad Request 400: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` My goal is to eliminate this error. Obviously, this has to do with the versions of some dependency or set of dependencies. Interestingly, the last endpoint in the API, which has a request parser within a namespace with no arguments, works perfectly, unlike the two other endpoints in the default namespace that do have arguments.

The API is built on flask_restx and uses reqparse.

The API code is here:

```
from flask_restx import Api, Resource, Namespace, reqparse, inputs
import flask
import process
from load_data import store_data


app = flask.Flask("restful_api")
api = Api(app, title="My API", description="This is an extremely useful API for performing tasks you would do with an API.", version="3.14")
data = {}
data.update(store_data())


class DefaultClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data

    def _replace_get(self, **args):
        default_args = {}
        args = {**default_args, **args}
        return process.replace(**args)

    def _find_get(self, **args):
        default_args = {"data": self.data["data"]}
        args = {**default_args, **args}
        return process.find_in_data_string(**args)


def set_up_worker():
    global defaultClass
    defaultClass = DefaultClass()


set_up_worker()

_replaceGetParser = reqparse.RequestParser()
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("txt",
                               type=str,
                               required=True,
                               help="Text to search ")
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("old",
                               type=str,
                               required=True,
                               help="Substring to replace ")
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("new",
                               type=str,
                               required=True,
                               help="Replacement for old ")
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("irrelevant_parameter",
                               type=int,
                               required=False,
                               default=5,
                               help="")
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("smart_casing",
                               type=inputs.boolean,
                               required=False,
                               default=True,
                               help="True if we should infer replacement capitalization from original casing. ")
_replaceGetParser.add_argument("case_sensitive",
                               type=inputs.boolean,
                               required=False,
                               default=True,
                               help="True if we should only replace case-sensitive matches ")

_findGetParser = reqparse.RequestParser()
_findGetParser.add_argument("window",
                            type=int,
                            required=False,
                            default=5,
                            help="Number of characters before and after first match to return ")
_findGetParser.add_argument("txt",
                            type=str,
                            required=False,
                            default="quick",
                            help="Your search term ")


@api.route('/replace', endpoint='replace', methods=['GET'])
@api.doc('defaultClass')
class ReplaceFrontend(Resource):

    @api.expect(_replaceGetParser)
    def get(self):
        args = _replaceGetParser.parse_args()
        return defaultClass._replace_get(**args)


@api.route('/find', endpoint='find', methods=['GET'])
@api.doc('defaultClass')
class FindFrontend(Resource):

    @api.expect(_findGetParser)
    def get(self):
        args = _findGetParser.parse_args()
        return defaultClass._find_get(**args)


retrievalNamespace = Namespace("retrieval", description="Data retrieval operations")


class RetrievalNamespaceClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data

    def _retrieval_retrieve_data_get(self, **args):
        default_args = {"data": self.data["data"]}
        args = {**default_args, **args}
        return process.return_data(**args)


def set_up_retrieval_worker():
    global retrievalNamespaceClass
    retrievalNamespaceClass = RetrievalNamespaceClass()


set_up_retrieval_worker()

_retrieval_retrieve_dataGetParser = reqparse.RequestParser()


@retrievalNamespace.route('/retrieval/retrieve_data', endpoint='retrieval/retrieve_data', methods=['GET'])
@retrievalNamespace.doc('retrievalNamespaceClass')
class Retrieval_retrieve_dataFrontend(Resource):

    @retrievalNamespace.expect(_retrieval_retrieve_dataGetParser)
    def get(self):
        args = _retrieval_retrieve_dataGetParser.parse_args()
        return retrievalNamespaceClass._retrieval_retrieve_data_get(**args)
api.add_namespace(retrievalNamespace)
```

I have had this problem with both pip-installed `gunicorn` and conda-installed `uwsgi`. I'm putting the file imported by the API at the end, since I think it is likely irrelevant what the function definitions are.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from flask_restx import abort


def replace(txt: str = '',  # apireq
            old: str = '',   # apireq
            new: str = '',  # apireq
            case_sensitive: bool = True,
            smart_casing: bool = True,
            irrelevant_parameter: int = 5):
    """
    Search and replace within a string, as long as the string and replacement
    contain no four letter words.

    arguments:
      txt: Text to search
      old: Substring to replace
      new: Replacement for old
      case_sensitive: True if we should only replace case-sensitive matches
      smart_casing: True if we should infer replacement capitalization
        from original casing.


    return
      return value
    """
    four_letter_words = [re.match('[a-zA-Z]{4}$', word).string
                         for word in ('%s %s' % (txt, new)).split()
                         if re.match('[a-zA-Z]{4}$', word)]
    if four_letter_words:
        error_message = ('Server refuses to process four letter word(s) %s'
                         % ', '.join(four_letter_words[:5])
                         + (', etc' if len(four_letter_words) > 5 else ''))
        abort(403, custom=error_message)
    return_value = {}
    if not case_sensitive:
        return_value['output'] = txt.replace(old, new)
    else:
        lowered = txt.replace(old, old.lower())
        return_value['output'] = lowered.replace(old.lower(), new)
    return return_value


def find_in_data_string(txt: str = "quick",  # req
                        window: int = 5,
                        data=None):  # noapi
    """
    Check if there is a match for your search string in our extensive database,
    and return the position of the first match with the surrounding text.

    arguments:
      txt: Your search term
      data: The server's text data
      window: Number of characters before and after first match to return
    """
    return_value = {}
    if txt in data:
        idx = data.find(txt)
        min_idx = max(idx-window, 0)
        max_idx = min(idx+len(txt)+window, len(data)-1)
        return_value['string_found'] = True
        return_value['position'] = idx
        return_value['surrounding_string'] = data[min_idx:max_idx]
        return_value['surrounding_string_indices'] = [min_idx, max_idx]
    else:
        return_value = {['string_found']: False}
    return return_value


def return_data(data=None):  # noapi
    """
    Return all the data in our text database.
    """
    with Popen(['which', 'aws'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE) as p:
        output = p.stdout.read()
    try:
        assert not output.strip()
    except AssertionError:
        abort(503, custom='The server is incorrectly configured.')
    return_value = {'data': data}
    return return_value
```

Comment: Fixed by downgrading some packages:
  - `jinja2=2.11.3`
  - `werkzeug=2.0.3`
  - `flask=1.1.2`
  - `itsdangerous=2.0.1`;

However, I'd like to be able to use new packages. Is the problem just that reqparse is too old and unmaintained?